# Regular Expression to match pattern

Tags: notepad++, regex

I am trying to find all matches for the two following lines:

```
:Potato: Potato(3) :
```

and

```
:Tomato: 11
```

Of course these words (Potato,Tomato) can be random words and the numbers from 1-99 .

Any help would be very appreciated.

Comment: What language/tool are you using? What have you tried? What is a "word" for you? Only alphabetics? Alphanumerics? Word character class `[A-Za-z0-9_]`? Alphanumerics with non latin characters? Everything that is not a space or punctuation? Something else?

Comment: hi Toto, "word" is only alphabetics no numbers or special characters just letters A-Z, spaces only the ones that are already above. (after the second " : " on both lines )

Comment: Also the tool is Notepad++

Comment: `:[A-Za-z]+: [0-9]+ |:[A-Za-z]+: [A-Za-z]+\([0-9]\) :`Tested at [Online regex tester and debugger: PHP, PCRE, Python, Golang and JavaScript](https://regex101.com/)

Comment: Did you meant to match like [this](https://regex101.com/r/09VL2z/14)? Otherwise can you please explain what you mean with ***all matches*** and in what context.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd>
- Find what: `:[a-z]+:\h*(?:[a-z]+\([1-9]\d?\)\h*:|[1-9]\d?\b)`
- **UNCHECK** *Match case*
- **CHECK** *Wrap around*
- **CHECK** *Regular expression*
- <kbd>Find All in Current Document</kbd>

**Explanation:**

```
:           # colon
[a-z]+      # 1 or more letter
:           # colon
\h*         # 0 or more horizontal spaces
(?:         # non capture group
  [a-z]+        # 1 or more letter
  \(            # opening parenthesis
  [1-9]         # digit between 1 and 9
  \d?           # 1 optional digit
  \)            # closing parenthesis
  \h*           # 0 or more horizontal spaces
  :             # colon
 |          # OR
  [1-9]         # digit between 1 and 9
  \d?           # 1 optional digit
  \b            # word boundary, make sure we haven't digit after
)           # end group
```

**Screenshot (before):**

[image]

**Screenshot (after):**

[image]